# FileNotFoundException when Using ExifInterface

Tags: java, android, rotation, exif, filenotfoundexception

I have been uploading images to FirebaseStorage, but often they are the wrong way around when displaying them. I have discovered the ExifInterface that can determined the orientation of the image and rotate and flip it if necessary.

When selecting the image from the gallery area on my phone I get this error.

[image: FileNotFoundError]

I can select the image on my phone from the gallery and It can be displayed on the page.

The differences between the URI address and the data is one `/`

```
Data.getData() address : content://media/external/images/media/53331

uri.toString() address: content:/media/external/images/media/53331
```

I'm using the uri address as the images absolute path of the image to be able to rotate it if necessary. I pass this value into another method called `modifyOrientation` which then rotates it. Once it is passed into the method it reaches the line

`ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(image_absolute_path);`

and then returns to the catch as the file was not found.

Below is the entire error I'm getting as well as all my code. How can I fix this issue that I'm having. So when I pass the URI across into the next method it actually has the correct address.

[image: Entire error]

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        final FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Displaying Image...");
            progressDialog.show();

            //imageUri = data.getData();
            //Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(profileImage);


            final Uri uri = data.getData();


            File file = new File(uri.toString());
            file.getAbsolutePath();

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
                modifyOrientation(bitmap,file.getAbsolutePath());
                profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap modifyOrientation(Bitmap bitmap, String image_absolute_path) throws IOException {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(image_absolute_path);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return rotate(bitmap, 90);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return rotate(bitmap, 180);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return rotate(bitmap, 270);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                return flip(bitmap, true, false);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                return flip(bitmap, false, true);

            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, float degrees) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degrees);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap bitmap, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(horizontal ? -1 : 1, vertical ? -1 : 1);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `Uri` is not a `File`.

Step #1: Delete `File file = new File(uri.toString());`

Step #2: Make sure that you are using [the Support Library edition of `ExifInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html)

Step #3: Call `getContentResolver()` on your `Activity` to get a `ContentResolver`

Step #4: Call `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri`, to get an `InputStream` on the content pointed to by that `Uri`

Step #5: Pass that `InputStream` to [the `ExifInterface` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream))

Step #6: Use that `ExifInterface` as you are presently, to determine the image orientation

Step #7: Once you get things working, move all of this I/O to a background thread

Comment: My error was that I was using passing the `Uri` to the ExifInterface constructor. Create an InputStream from the `Uri` was the solution.
`contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)`